# ios Invalid compression specifier with string

Tags: ios, objective-c, url

I have a url string:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://gmt.telekom-dienste.de/query?callback=jQuery16203304807513486594_1405512207013&gmt_request=%7B%22boundary%22%3A%7B%22n%22%3A52.84508248794807%2C%22s%22%3A52.16803549716245%2C%22w%22%3A12.379694196093737%2C%22e%22%3A14.472589703906237%7D%2C%22queries%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22points%22%2C%22layer%22%3A%22shops1%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22points%22%2C%22layer%22%3A%22shops2%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22points%22%2C%22layer%22%3A%22shops3%22%7D%5D%7D&zoom=9&_=1405512557274"]
```

but the xcode tels Invalid compression specifier B and in `_request=%7B%22boundary` and cuts off the url
what is the problem?

Comment: First of all your syntax is wrong. Its should be like :- [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MY string = %@",string];

Comment: Why you are using stringWithFormat here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Invalid compression specifier B*  -- This is because string contains '%' sign. and B is treated as format specifier. And there is no such format specifier exist.

Actual problem is your string has '%'. And the escape code for a percent sign is "%%". So, To make it correct NSString you should replace '%' with '%%'.

But if your are making NSURL with this string then you can use this directly --

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://gmt.telekom-dienste.de/query?callback=jQuery16203304807513486594_1405512207013&gmt_request=%7B%22boundary%22%3A%7B%22n%22%3A52.84508248794807%2C%22s%22%3A52.16803549716245%2C%22w%22%3A12.379694196093737%2C%22e%22%3A14.472589703906237%7D%2C%22queries%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22points%22%2C%22layer%22%3A%22shops1%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22points%22%2C%22layer%22%3A%22shops2%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22points%22%2C%22layer%22%3A%22shops3%22%7D%5D%7D&zoom=9&_=1405512557274"];
```

Comment: but I need to place it in Core Data

Answer (score 0):

Check with

```
`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://gmt.telekom-dienste.de/query?callback=jQuery16203304807513486594_1405512207013&gmt_request=%7B%22boundary%22%3A%7B%22n%22%3A52.84508248794807%2C%22s%22%3A52.16803549716245%2C%22w%22%3A12.379694196093737%2C%22e%22%3A14.472589703906237%7D%2C%22queries%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22points%22%2C%22layer%22%3A%22shops1%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22points%22%2C%22layer%22%3A%22shops2%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22points%22%2C%22layer%22%3A%22shops3%22%7D%5D%7D&zoom=9&_=1405512557274"];`
```

Answer (score 0):

In you string %22 indicates double quotes("). This means your  string value is ended before this. That is the problem.

Comment: and how can I fix it?